# Merge Crystal reports .NET 4 C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, crystal-reports, merge, reporting

Good day,

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to merge 3 Simila reports into 1 at runtime in report viewer. I have 3 reports that are very similar and need to all run at the same time, currently I have to show the viewer 3 times to show all the reports. I would idealy like to set it up so page 1 is report 1,page 2 is report2, page 3 is report 3...they are all longer than a page but I am using this as an example.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's impossible put 3 reports inside 1 reportviewer.
I suggest an easy way to solve your problem:
create a **new blank report** then **insert as subreports** the 3 reports.

Be careful, subreports can't contain others subreports inside.